# How (un)comfortable to play are these large chords?

Tags: piano, chords, technique, physiology

I'm wondering if you could tell me how possible/comfortable this is to play? Particularly the 2nd & 3rd chords.

I can reach the notes myself on the piano but my ring/index finger end up at the top of the piano key which makes it hard to actually press down. Just wondering whether a good pianist would have issues with those chords.

Quarter note = 50bpm

[image: The largest chords span a diminished 10th (i.e., major 9th) from G# to Bb in both hands]

Comment: The comfort/ease depends on the size of your hands. But those bass clef chords are so dense no one will be able to tell whether you're playing the right notes or not! Unless they're aiming at mud, piano parts don't have such closely spaced parts really low down. Those chords are the treble clef chords restated two octaves down, which suggests this might be a piece you found online, written by someone who's still learning to write piano parts...

Comment: Do not ask the internet for fingerings, for it will say both yes and no. Whether something is possible/easy/comfortable for a pianist depends on the pianist as much as on the score.

Comment: @BrianTHOMAS I wrote the music but, out of curiosity, why does the fact that both hands play the same chords 2 octaves apart indicate someone new to piano writing?

Comment: Typically, piano music treats the bass (left hand) and the treble notes (right hand) as separate entities, where the left hand might be playing a bass note or something similar while the right hand plays most of the notes in the chord voicing. The fact that both hands are playing identical voicings is indicative of someone who has yet to develop this style of writing, which often means a beginner writer.

Comment: OP may wish to research "Lower Interval Limits" (muddiness in bass register) and "Harmonic Series" (notes' overtones reinforcing each other) as they relate to voicings, as these are concepts that dictate the conventional piano chord voicing style.

Answer (score 1):

I easily reach a tenth, but that second chord is close to impossible, especially in the left hand. If given a moment to set it up, I can just barely stretch my fingers around the keys and get it. I suppose with some practice I might get fast enough at that contortion to get it at speed, but it's always going to be scary.

The third chord is a little rough in the left hand but doable, and completely fine in the right hand.

Answer (score 1):

Don't always assume that decent pianists have wide enough hand spans to even play this without needing to arpeggiate. I passed my Grade 10 Royal Conservatory of Music Piano Performance exam, and my hands can each span only an octave without hitting inner notes. They can span a ninth, but then they must hit inner notes a second away from the notes at the thumbs. This means that I find the second and third chords to be **impossible** to play without using arpeggios.

Answer (score 0):

A good pianist with a wide enough hand span should have no trouble with those chords.

The 2nd and 3rd chords in particular are fine, especially since the piece isn't very fast, but they do require experience and skill. The technique is, as you say, to move the hand toward the back of the keys, but it does require a wide hand-span to comfortably sound all the notes.

Some pertinent, more detailed comments on hand position, including pictures, can be found at [How to exercise my fingers in extreme bending when playing piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/107674/70803)